# Read a csv file with two consecutive delimiters using C++

Tags: c++, csv, delimiter, sudoku

I am trying to generate a Sudoku grid from a CSV file.
The code I have made works for this kind of file :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
...
```

But I need it to create the grid with this kind of file :

```
; ; 5; ;;1; ;;1
3; ; ;;;;6; ;
;7;;;;2;;;4
;;1;3;;5;;8;
...
```

Here is my code :

```
int grid[9][9];
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open(inputFileName);

    for (int row = 0; row <9 ; row++) {
        string line;
        getline(inputFile, line);
        if (!inputFile.good())
            break;
        stringstream ss(line);

        for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            size_t si = line.find_first_not_of("\n 123456789");
            string ch = line.substr(0, si); 
            if (ch.length() == 0) break; 
            istringstream converter(ch);
            converter >> grid[row][col];
            if ((si + 1u) >= line.length() || si == std::string::npos) break; 
            line = line.substr(si + 1u, std::string::npos); 
        }
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 8; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == 0) { 
                cout << "  "; 
            }
            else {
                cout << grid[i][j] << " "; 
            }
            if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0) {
                cout << "|"; 
            }
            if (j == 8)
                cout << "  " << (i + 1);
        }
        cout << endl;
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
            for (int s = 0; s <= 20; s++)
                cout << "-";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Do you have any idea to do it with several consecutive delimiters ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop `for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)` breaks too early at `if (ch.length() == 0) break;` - every double colon `";;"` stops further reading. Also the second break `if ((si + 1u) >= line.length() || si == std::string::npos) break;` will match too early.

I would implement splitting each input line into the single values by a helper function. This might use some more lines but is much better to read and debug:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 9; row++) 
{
  string line;
  getline(inputFile, line);
  if (!inputFile.good())
  {
    break; // handle error 
  }
  size_t delimiterPos = line.find_first_not_of("\n 123456789");
  if (delimiterPos == std::string::npos)
  {
    break; // handle error
  }
  char delimiter = line[delimiterPos];
  vector<string> singleValues = split(clearBlanks(line), delimiter);
  if (singleValues.size() != 9)
  {
    break; // handle error 
  }
  for (size_t col = 0; col < singleValues.size(); col++)
  {
    grid[row][col] = singleValues[col].size() > 0 ? stoi(singleValues[col]) : 0;
  }
}
```

with the help of two add. functions - one clearing all blanks from a string:

```
std::string clearBlanks(const std::string& input)
{
  std::string returnValue = input;
  size_t pos = returnValue.find(" ");
  while (pos != std::string::npos)
  {
    returnValue.erase(pos, 1);
    pos = returnValue.find(" ");
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

and a second splitting a string into an array of strings:

```
vector<string> split(const string& str, char delim)
{
  vector<string> tokens;
  size_t prev = 0, pos = 0;
  do
  {
    pos = str.find(delim, prev);
    if (pos == string::npos)
    {
      pos = str.length();
    }
    tokens.push_back(str.substr(prev, pos - prev));
    prev = pos + 1;
  } while (pos < str.length());
  return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help! 
I just replaced the line "line.find_first_not_of("\n 123456789")" by "line.find_first_of(",;\t")" in order to focus on the delimiters I want to handle. 
The code works great, except on the last line, where each number is replaced by "-858993460" but if add an empty line on my file (opened with notepad++), it works perfectly. I will try to find where is the problem.
Thanks again.

Comment: The `if (!inputFile.good())` says `false`when the end of file is reached. The line was read successfully but the end of file was reached -- so after the last line read the file say "not good". Moving that line to the end of the loop might fix it .. and checking the string's length might be sufficient for a "read succeeded" check.

Comment: I replaced this line by if(inputFile.eof()) {inputFile.close()} and it works perfectly, but thank you for your answer